# CSV output is duplicated

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to output the database selected rows in csv format, but it outputs me duplicated values instead of single one. I want it to have columns and below the column the value. The output:
onlineId,paramId,paramValue 4cd87b00dddca780fcaf66d0108b25f6,4cd87b00dddca780fcaf66d0108b25f6,1,1,11,11

The code below:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('onlineId', 'paramId', 'paramValue'));

$host = "localhost";
$database = "keytarget";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $database, $username, $password);

//Run our query
$sql = "
        SELECT
            ui.onlineId, uin.paramId, uin.paramValue
        FROM
            v5_userinfo ui
        JOIN
            v5_userinfo_number uin
        ON
            uin.userId = ui.id
        ;
        ";

$statement = $con->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becouse when you retrieve the data it gives you a mix between an associative array and a normal array [More info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). So your $row var is something like:

```
array(
   [0]=>4cd87b00dddca780fcaf66d0108b25f6
   [onlineId]=>4cd87b00dddca780fcaf66d0108b25f6
   [1]=>1
   [paramId]=>1
   [2]=>11
   [paramValue]=>11
)
```

So your solution could be:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $array=array($row[0],$row[1],$row[2]);
    fputcsv($output, $array);
}
```

Or an easier one:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```